# Testing JQuery autocomplete ui with cucumber

Tags: jquery-ui, cucumber, capybara, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I got this cucumber sceanario:

```
When I fill in "End User" with "john"
Then wait
Then wait
When I click "John Doe"
Then show me the page
```

Step definitions:

```
Then /^wait$/ do
  sleep 2
end

When /^(?:|I )click "([^"]*)"$/ do |selector|
  find(":contains('#{selector}')").click
end
```

It passes but it doesn't select a user."End User" equals "john" in 'show me the page'.

I even can't get it to work in a javascript console. The following code does not select anything.

```
$(":contains('John Doe')").last().trigger('click')
# => [<a class=​"ui-corner-all" tabindex=​"-1"...
```

How can I script a autocomplete select? Be it in pure javascript or in cucumber.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Give this a go

```
When /^I type in "([^\"]*)" into autocomplete list "([^\"]*)" and I choose "([^\"]*)"$/ do |typed, input_name,should_select|
   page.driver.browser.execute_script %Q{ $('input[data-autocomplete]').trigger("focus") }
   fill_in("#{input_name}",:with => typed)
   page.driver.browser.execute_script %Q{ $('input[data-autocomplete]').trigger("keydown") }
   sleep 1
   page.driver.browser.execute_script %Q{ $('.ui-menu-item a:contains("#{should_select}")').trigger("mouseenter").trigger("click"); }
end
```

Use like so

```
And I type in "Foo" into autocomplete list "input_id" and I choose "Foobar"
```

Comment: This solution worked for me, thanks for sharing. Though i changed page.driver.browser.execute_script to simply page.execute_script it is shorter.

Answer (score 4):

I myself bumped into the same pain spot too. After spending few hours on this, I have one good helper that works both with selenium and polstergeist plus no usage of `sleep()`. The following code has been tested with Capybara 2.1.0:

```
  def fill_autocomplete(field, options = {})
    fill_in field, with: options[:with]

    page.execute_script %Q{ $('##{field}').trigger('focus') }
    page.execute_script %Q{ $('##{field}').trigger('keydown') }
    selector = %Q{ul.ui-autocomplete li.ui-menu-item a:contains("#{options[:select]}")}

    page.should have_selector('ul.ui-autocomplete li.ui-menu-item a')
    page.execute_script %Q{ $('#{selector}').trigger('mouseenter').click() }
  end
```

Basically, I tell Capybara to fill in the input field then use JS to trigger the `keydown` event to activate autocomplete. However instead of `sleep()`, I take advantage of `page.should have_selector('ul.ui-autocomplete li.ui-menu-item a')` that wait till the dropdown list appeared. Then I use JS to trigger the `mouseenter` event then click. I wish that there are better way than doing things with JS eval, but this is the most reliable solution that I could come up.

Answer (score 0):

While this is not a solution, this could lead you down the path of the solution:

the click event is bound to the UL, no the a or li:

$('ul.ui-autocomplete').click();

However, this didn't work for me.  I imagine the click event relies on some sort of state with the (a)s and the (li)s.  It adds a few classes and an ID to the currently hovered item which I simulated...

$('a.ui-corner-all').attr('id','ui-active-menuitem')
$('a.ui-corner-all').addClass('ui-active-menuitem')

Still no dice.  No errors, but no action either.

This should lead to the correct path...I just wish I could have figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

You need to first trigger a mouseover, then a click.