# mouseMove for Watin

Tags: c#, selenium, watin

I'm able to perform a mouse move over that triggers a menu down with Selenium's mouseMove function, but have codded most of my browser automation is Watin. Is there a suitable replacement for this option in Watin?

I've tried

```
div.FireEvent("onMouseMove");
div.MouseEnter();
```

with no luck. I target the same div classes. mouseMove for Selenium works, onmouseMove for Watin doesn't.

Comment: Not yet. I've put off the troublesome project and moved on to something else. I'll come back to it though.

Answer (score 0):

Working with some cranky form validation, I had to call the javascript change() method directly to get form validation to fire as Watin's element click() wasn't doing it.

Calling change() looked like this.

```
var jqElement = string.Format("window.jQuery({0})", GetJavascriptElementReference());
DomContainer.Eval(string.Format("{0}.change()", jqElement));
```

Obviously you'd need to change the window.jQuery... portion to point at your form, and change the change() method to the appropriate mouseover method you need called.

The negative here is the fragility due to calling a specific javascript method in your test code.

Another example of calling javascript directly can be seen in my answer here:  [Autocomplete DropDown Menu Testing using WatiN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434278/autocomplete-dropdown-menu-testing-using-watin/7449030#7449030)

Comment: What does the jQuery({0}) represent? Will I be able to identify my element by class or some other attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Give mouse move a try...

```
div.FireEvent("mouseenter");
div.FireEvent("mousemove");
```

Comment: If I leave out the 'on' it fires an error in the troubleshooting logs. "Invalid argument."