# Specflow test for jquery ui autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

How to write specflow test for jQuery Ui autocomplete. Thanks!

```
var practices = [
{ "Data": "1", "value": "abc" },
{ "Data": "2", "value": "efg" }
];
$('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
    lookup: practices,
    onSelect: function (suggestion) {
    //do something
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I was looking in below link:
[Autocomplete DropDown Menu Testing using WatiN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434278/autocomplete-dropdown-menu-testing-using-watin)

The line which did the trick was.

```
ie.Eval(@"$('#tags').autocomplete('search')");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try autocomplete example as shown below

```js
$(document).on('ready',function(){
      $(function() {
        var arrLinks = [
          {
            data: 1,
            value : "Helloo"
      
          },
          {
            data: 2,
            value : "World"
      
          }
        ];
        $("input[name=search]").autocomplete({
            source: arrLinks
        }).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
            return $("<li>").data("ui-autocomplete-item", item).append("<a>" + item.value + "</a>").appendTo(ul);
        };
      });

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="search">
```

Comment: When I enter text for searching through specflow no result appears.

Comment: @RajeshKumar Try typing "Hello" or "World" you will be able to get the results. It's working fine.