# rails3-jquery-autocomplete: how to test with RSpec and Capybara?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, rspec, capybara

I'm using Rails 3.2.8 with

- gem 'jquery-rails', '2.1.2'
- gem 'rails3-jquery-autocomplete', '1.0.9'
- gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.4'
- gem 'capybara', '1.1.3'
- gem 'capybara-webkit', '0.12.1'

I've recently converted a select drop-down to an autocomplete (using rails3-jquery-autocomplete) and am trying to update my request specs to fill in the autocomplete.

My approach has been to create a helper as shown in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/919459):

```
def fill_autocomplete(field, options = {})
  fill_in field, :with => options[:with]

  selector = "ul.ui-autocomplete a:contains('#{options[:select]}')"

  page.should have_selector selector
  page.execute_script "$(\"#{selector}\").mouseenter().click()"
end
```

If I test that with Webkit, the test fails with this message:

```
expected css "ul.ui-autocomplete a:contains('Firstname Lastname')" to return something.
```

If I test with Selenium, as I watch the test proceed in Firefox, I do *not* see the drop-down pick list appearing. Adding a `sleep 3` to wait for the drop-down doesn't help.

I see [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/50) that there is a related but somewhat old issue with capybara-webkit, something about when a field is filled in, it is immediately blurred, which would of course prevent the autocomplete pick list from appearing. But that doesn't seem to jibe with others who have gotten this to work.

Is it currently possible to test a form that includes a rails3-jquery-autocomplete field with RSpec and Capybara? How? If not, is there a way to manually fill in the corresponding, hidden `id` field so I can still test that the form creates the correct data?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally got autocomplete tests working at least with the Selenium driver.

The solution is to put focus on the field and issue a keydown event.

I confirmed this first with manual testing in a browser.  If I use the mouse (not Ctrl-V) to paste a search term into an autocomplete field, nothing happens--no drop-down pick list is displayed. This is apparently the equivalent of what happens when Capybara sends a fill_in command. However, after the term is in the field, while focus is still on the field, if I touch any key, e.g. the Shift key, the pick list appears. So apparently the pick list only appears when a key is pressed.

**Option 1**

One solution is to extend the function from the original question as follows:

```
def fill_autocomplete(field, options = {})
  fill_in field, :with => options[:with]

  page.execute_script %Q{ $('##{field}').trigger("focus") }
  page.execute_script %Q{ $('##{field}').trigger("keydown") }
  selector = "ul.ui-autocomplete a:contains('#{options[:select]}')"

  page.should have_selector selector
  page.execute_script "$(\"#{selector}\").mouseenter().click()"
end
```

and then call it like this:

```
fill_autocomplete "to_contact_name", with: "Jone", select: "Bob Jones"
```

**Option 2**

A similar approach, adapted from the [Steak test](https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete/blob/master/lib/steak/autocomplete.rb) in the main rails3-jquery-autocomplete gem, uses the standard fill_in, followed by this choose_autocomplete_result:

```
def choose_autocomplete_result(item_text, input_selector="input[data-autocomplete]")
  page.execute_script %Q{ $('#{input_selector}').trigger("focus") }
  page.execute_script %Q{ $('#{input_selector}').trigger("keydown") }
  # Set up a selector, wait for it to appear on the page, then use it.
  item_selector = "ul.ui-autocomplete li.ui-menu-item a:contains('#{item_text}')"
  page.should have_selector item_selector
  page.execute_script %Q{ $("#{item_selector}").trigger("mouseenter").trigger("click"); }
end
```

which is called like this:

```
fill_in "to_contact_name", :with => "Jone"
choose_autocomplete_result "Bob Jones", "#to_contact_name"
```

I've adopted the second approach for my tests. It seems pretty reliable with Selenium but doesn't work with webkit, which is too bad, since the Selenium tests are quite slow by comparison. A solution that works under webkit would be welcome!

Comment: yep, it didnt work with Webkit. I test it on capybara + poltergeist(webkit env),it crashed on the have_selector validation. when I debug it by take a screencast, I found the autocomplete item was did generated, but the page object cant recognize it

Comment: Your option 1 solution is not working due to the fact `:contains` are not valid W3C CSS selectors (this is jQuery only). I fixed it with solution listed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355586/testing-jquery-autocomplete-ui-with-cucumber under my name

Answer (score 4):

I myself bumped into the same pain spot too. After spending few hours on this, I have one good helper that works both with selenium and polstergeist plus no usage of `sleep()`. The following code has been tested with Capybara 2.1.0:

```
  def fill_autocomplete(field, options = {})
    fill_in field, with: options[:with]

    page.execute_script %Q{ $('##{field}').trigger('focus') }
    page.execute_script %Q{ $('##{field}').trigger('keydown') }
    selector = %Q{ul.ui-autocomplete li.ui-menu-item a:contains("#{options[:select]}")}

    page.should have_selector('ul.ui-autocomplete li.ui-menu-item a')
    page.execute_script %Q{ $('#{selector}').trigger('mouseenter').click() }
  end
```

Basically, I tell Capybara to fill in the input field then use JS to trigger the `keydown` event to activate autocomplete. However instead of `sleep()`, I take advantage of `page.should have_selector('ul.ui-autocomplete li.ui-menu-item a')` that wait till the dropdown list appeared. Then I use JS to trigger the `mouseenter` event then click. I wish that there are better way than doing things with JS eval, but this is the most reliable solution that I could come up.

Comment: Keydown is not firing the autocomplete code with Poltergeist. I have verified this by adding a dummy input box on the screen, and attaching a keydown listener for it that just makes a test object visible or invisible. Then I take a screenshot before and after in the test. So I know the keydown event is firing, but for whatever reason it is NOT triggering the autocomplete code that works so well in the browser. Do you have any idea at all? I have spent almost 48 work hours on this and I just can't get past it.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone needs some code for inspiration (took me a while even after reading this thread), this works:

```
      context "with 5 items results" do
        before do
          5.times { FactoryGirl.create(:item, title: "chinese " + random_string(5) ) }
          page.execute_script("$('input#search_param').val('chinese')")
          page.execute_script("$('input#search_param').trigger('focus')")
          page.execute_script("$('input#search_param').trigger('keydown')")
        end
        specify { page.evaluate_script("$('input#search_param').val()").should == 'chinese' }
        specify { page.should have_css "#autocomplete-menu li", count: 5 }
      end
```

Thanks Mark Berry for the inspiration.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is the capybara [send_keys](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara%2FNode%2FElement%3Asend_keys) method:

`find('#my_object_id').send_keys 'bob'`

I prefer this option over injecting javascript to fire keydown/focus/mouseenter events.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using page.execute_script, I filled up input with blank after my input so that the event will fire up.

```
fill_in("query", :with => "ma")
fill_in("query", :with => "")
# autocomplete suggestions will come up
all('.autocomplete div').first.should have_content("mango")
# other assertions
```